# Simple curl request failing - why?

Tags: curl, express

I'm following a codeschool project, and while this curl command delivers JSON for the instructor, (and the route delivers JSON when I hit it from the browser), it fails in my terminal. It's not even hitting the route!

```
OlympicsMEAN [master] :> curl -i localhost:8181/sports
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 47
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: /sports/
Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2016 15:43:35 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Redirecting to <a href="/sports/">/sports/</a>
```

The pertinent route (in Express) is

```
app.get("/sports", (request, response) => {
  console.log('hit /sports endpoint');
  response.json( ['Cycling', 'Waitlyfting'] );
});
```

I even tried this... with the same result

```
curl -iH "Accept: application/json" localhost:8181/sports
```

I thought I had a handle on CURL. What are some possible reasons for it to fail, when the route works just fine via a browser request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I really got what you intend to,
but if you meant curl to return whatever is "behind" the URL you specified,
then you might need a "-L" option.

As the result you gave from the curl call indicates a 300 code, 
a regular browser will just follow the new location from the "Location" header,
while curl will do this only when "-L" is in effect.

Comment: this is the first time I ever had to use -L, and it worked! I am, however, confused why my curl requests in the past have always got JSON back without it. Thanks though.

Comment: Whether you need a "-L" or not fully depends on what the server side is expecting. The return message from curl without -L indicates the server wants to have /sports/ (with a trailing "/"). So, if you had given such URL, "-L" could be omitted.

Comment: That means my server is somehow different than in the past, even though the route specifies "/sports" with no trailing slash. More puzzlement. But now I have something I can google. Thanks!